# How to extract part of header location url as variable in insomnia

Tags: javascript, insomnia

I need to extract part of header location url (ticket number) to use on another request in insomnia, but I have no idea how to get that.

What I did so far was:

1. First Request: https://domain-1.com
   Response Header Location: https://domain-2.com/tickets/ABC-1234
2. Created a tag for the second request - [https://domain-1.com/{response-header}](https://domain-1.com/%7Bresponse-header%7D)

```
Function to perform:  Response
Attribute - Header
Request - (the other url)
Header name - Location
Trigger behaviour - when expired
Max age - 60s
```

Live preview: https://domain-2.com/tickets/ABC-1234

But on the query url, i'm getting: https://domain-1.com/https://domain-2.com/tickets/ABC-1234

And I expect: https://domain-1.com/ABC-1234

Can someone give me a light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.

Create a folder, put the both requests on it and edit folder environment with the information below:

```
{
    "location": "{{% response 'header', 'req_xxxxxxxxxx', 'b64::TG9xxxx', 'when-expired', 60 %}}",
    "code": "{{ location | replace('https://domain-2.com/tickets/', '')}}"
}
```

Then use the tag "code" on request:

```
https://domain-1.com/{{code}}
```